# How can I set a variable in PHP when I click an image?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, image

What I want is two images that appear, and when one is clicked that image is set to the winner. I have two variables, $left and $right. When say the left image is clicked I want $left = 'winner'; and $right = 'loser'; How do I do this?

Comment: PHP alone cannot do this.  PHP only does server-side processing, and the server has no idea when or if a user clicks on an image (unless that image has a link or some kind of JavaScript `onClick` action).  You'll probably need to use AJAX for this.

Comment: forget PHP, you don't want your server doing this sort of work. Just use JavaScript. And if you don't know JS it's syntax if fairly similar to PHP so it should'n be to hard to learn. See http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/

Comment: PHP alone could do this but why would you want to? You could make each image href = current page with get vars to identify the winner. ex: /somepage.php?winner=left and then handle your display accordingly. You don't mention what the purpose of something like this is - like maybe a test of some kind - so we don't know if you want to store the results or anything. Either way, JS would likely be a better way to handle this based on your brief question.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, that means you are not able to do that, in PHP you are generating an html document, you cannot handle the user events this way.

What you can do is:
-You can use JavaScript (and ajax if you need to handle this event in the server)
-The image is a link to an PHP page(itself if you want to), and you pass an parameter about the image the user click, but the page will be reloaded.

It really depends on what you are going to do after the user click the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the HTML, have the code thus:
2. On the web server create the script vote.php. This will receive the vote thus the HTTP GET method, with the name/value pair being the corresponding vote. You need to get this script to update your voting system and the deliver a new HTML page to the browser.

This is a very simplified system. More complex methods can include using AJAX and also to ensure that mutliple voting does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use javascript in this way:

```
<img id="left" value="" onClick="checkWinner(this.id)">
<img id="right" value="" onClick="checkWinner(this.id)">

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkWinner(clicked_id)
{
    var winner = clicked_id;
    var winningPicture = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
    var losingPicture = "";

    if (winner == "right") {
        losingPicture = document.getElementById('left');
    }

    else { 
        losingPicture = document.getElementById('right');
    }

    winningPicture.value = "winner";
    losingPicture.value = "loser";

    winningPicture.style.border = "2px solid green";
    losingPicture.style.border = "2px solid red";
```

}

I know it's a bit long winded but then you can carry out something with PHP like POST to a script sending image values.

That's my proposal anyhow.